# Python Beautifulsoup, get href tag, in a tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i had problem with getting `href` tag, so my case like this,
this is the `html` file :

```
<div class="list-product with-sidebar">
 <a class="frame-item" href="./produk-a.html" target="_blank" title="Produk A">

 </a>
 <a class="frame-item" href="./produk-b.html" target="_blank" title="Produk B">

 </a>
</div>
```

so here my code

```
    def get_category_item_list(category):
        base_url = 'https://www.website.com/'
        res = session.get(base_url+category)
        res = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html.parser')
        all_title = res.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'frame-item'})
        data_titles = []
        for title in all_title:
            product_link = title.get('a')['href']
            data_titles.append(product_link)
        return data_titles
```

what i want to get is, `href` links.. like this

```
produk-a.html
produk-b.html
```

when i try to run it.. it wont let me get link on `href`, they give error code :

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that your problem lies in this line :

```
product_link = title.get('a')['href']
```

You already have a list of "a" elements, so you probably just need :

```
product_link = title['href']
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't share with us the website, so one problem might be that the website block User Agents that looks like a bot (requests's user agent). Debugging may help here, you can print the content of the page with `resp.content/text`.

I created an HTML file called `index.html` and then I read the file and scrape it's content. I changed a little bit the code and it seems to be work fine.

`soup.find` returns an `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>`, so you can access it's attributes with `attribute['a']`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('index.html') as f:
    html_content = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
data_titles = []
for a in soup.find('div', class_='list-product with-sidebar').find_all('a'):
    data_titles.append(a['href'].split('/')[1])
print(data_titles)
# ['produk-a.html', 'produk-b.html']
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="list-product with-sidebar">
            <a
                class="frame-item"
                href="./produk-a.html"
                target="_blank"
                title="Produk A"
            >
            </a>
            <a
                class="frame-item"
                href="./produk-b.html"
                target="_blank"
                title="Produk B"
            >
            </a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

For your exact output,

1. you are already iterating over anchor tags
2. you would need to split by "/" and choose the last element

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html = """<div class="list-product with-sidebar">
 <a class="frame-item" href="./produk-a.html" target="_blank" title="Produk A">

 </a>
 <a class="frame-item" href="./produk-b.html" target="_blank" title="Produk B">

 </a>
</div>"""

res = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for a in res.findAll('a', attrs={'class':'frame-item'}):
    print(a["href"].split("/")[-1])
```

Output:

```
produk-a.html
produk-b.html
```